# WPF Zebra EPL2 Printing issue

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am trying to print some labels to a Zebra printer via EPL2.  Doing some searching for raw printing [point me to this.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091)  The problem with that link is its for a Windows Forms and not a WPF Application.  That means that `pd.PrinterSettings` and `RawPrinterHelper` are not available in the WPF application.  So what is the correct way for WPF Application to correctly print out RAW data?

Comment: I don't know whether this might be of any help or not, but you might learn something from this tip: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/802428/How-to-send-a-command-to-a-Zebra-QLn-Printer-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use [`LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.localprintserver.getdefaultprintqueue(v=vs.110).aspx) to get your default [`PrintQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printqueue(v=vs.110).aspx).  From there you can get the `PrintQueue.FullName`.

After that, copy the `RawPrinterHelper` found in the link you provided.  Call the same method in the link and pass it the RAW data.

```
var rawData = GetRAWData();
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(
     LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue().FullName, rawData);
```

If you want to use the `PrintDialog` method:

```
var rawData = GetRAWData();

PrintDialog pd  = new PrintDialog();
if(pd.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrintQueue.FullName, rawData);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve issue that RawPrinterHelper is still not available in the WPF Application.  I am using the namespace System.IO, System.Drawing.Printing, and System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Comment: @Xaphann Like I said in the answer, you copy the entire class from the example you posted in your link.  I added `System.IO` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices` and `RawPrinterHelper` builds just fine.

Comment: sorry read that too early in the morning and got confused :(  thanks